# Django Learning

Tags: python, django

I have started learning Django.I am following a tutorial series. Here after some tutorials they started **class-based views**.Should I give more focus on **Function-based view** or **Class-based view** for better learning.Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful to link to the tutorial. As usual with programming tools, each of these exist for their own use case.  What are you planning on applying this to? If you simply want to learn just to increase your knowledge, why not learn both?

Comment: you need to know both of them. But Class-based view is better. And 
more commonly used. Also in django rest framework Views are only Class-based view. But you can write views on Function-based view. But it not conveniently. 
PS sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

There was a period that function based programming was only there. They were made to address the basic use cases. However, the issue was that they were very basic, and was difficult to expand or customize them (other than utilizing arrangements parameters).

To address those issues, the class-based views was created.